# Laravel: can't login user after revoke token in api testst

Tags: php, laravel, api

After I revoke user's token with function:

```
public function logout(Request $r)  
{
    $r->user()->token()->revoke();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully logged out'
    ], 200);
}
```

I can't login with:

```
$user=User::where('email',$r->email)->first();
    if($user)
    {
            $credentials = $r->only('email', 'password');

            if(!Auth::attempt($credentials)){
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
            }

            $user = $r->user();

            $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
            $token = $tokenResult->token;

            $token->save();

            $data = [
                'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
                'token_type' => 'Bearer',
                'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                        $tokenResult->token->expires_at
                )->toDateTimeString()
            ];



        return response()->json(['data'=>$data,'message'=>'Successfully logged','status'=>'success'], 200);
```

Because I get 'Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist.' in response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is something to do with how you called `Auth`. Check how you imported it (if you have) bellow your namespace. You can use `use \Auth;` or just not import it and use a slash before it and it should work fine.

On tinker I can call `Auth::attempt()` and `\Auth::attempt()` without any errors.

So, for a quick fix, try putting a `\` before `Auth`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't help. This situation happen only when I run test where I login->logout->login back. When I test login manually through Postman it doesn't happen.